# Create cube using dimensions?

Tags: opengl, geometry, vertex

Is there an openGL function for creating a 3D cube using it's dimensions as input parameters? 
If not what algorithm would i use for generating the cube's vertex array?

What would be the easiest way to create a cube that does not require calculating the vertex array by hand?

Comment: Create a cube, using vertex unit points, and then, use scale transformation to do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an unitary cube. It is very easy to create it:

It's vertexes are:

```
GLfloat vertex[] = { -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  // 0
                      1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  // 1
                      1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   // 2
                     -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   // 3
                     -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // 4
                      1.0, -1.0, -1.0, // 5
                      1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  // 6
                     -1.0, 1.0, -1.0}; // 7
```

Now, create an array of how the faces are connected. Using QUAD as exemple,

```
GLuint faces[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3,
                   1, 5, 6, 2,
                   5, 4, 7, 6,
                   7, 4, 0, 3,
                   3, 2, 6, 7,
                   0, 4, 5, 1 };
```

Let's say that you create a function, called `cube()`, in which you passed this coordinates to the driver.

Now, to have any kind of cube, just specify the scale transformation to transform this unitary cube. For example, to make a cube of 4 units:

```
scale(4.0, 4.0, 4.0);
cube();
```

and so on